# Formula within vba as a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to simply get the these formulas as a variable in VBA.

*Cell C1 is merged until F1.* The following returns desired values.

**Formulas:**

`=LEFT(C1,FIND(" ",C1)-1)` = FirstWord

`=MID(C1,SEARCH(" - ",C1)+3,4)` = 123

**VBA:**

```
Dim SUBname, SUBnum As String
SUBname = Formula = "=LEFT(Selection,FIND("" "",Selection)-1)"
SUBnum = Formula = "=MID(Selection,SEARCH("" - "",Selection)+3,4)"
Debug.Print "SubName: "; SUBname
Debug.Print "Sub#: "; SUBnum & vbNewLine
```

Debug returns `False` for both.

The prior part of my code selects the merged header. I would like to stick with selection if I can.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `SUBname  = LEFT(Selection,INSTR(Selection," ")-1)`

Comment: `SUBname = Formula = "=LEFT(Selection,FIND("" "",Selection)-1)"` will set the variable `SUBname` to `True`or `False` according to the comparison of `Formula` and `"=LEFT(Selection,FIND("" "",Selection)-1)"`.

Comment: VBA has inbuilt functions to do this... `Left`, `Mid`, and `InStr`.

Comment: BTW, in `Dim SUBname, SUBnum As String`, only SUBnum is a String, SUBname is a Variant. You have to be explicit of each variable in vba.

Answer (score 3):

Left and Mid are vba functions use them:

```
SUBname = LEFT(Selection,INSTR(Selection," ")-1)
```

And

```
SUBnum = MID(Selection,INSTR(Selection," - ")+3,4)
```

The reason you are getting `False` is the result is asking if `Formula` is equal to the formula string.  Which it is not an thus it returns `False` to the variable.

Comment: How would I be able to Upper case the left formula?

Comment: Wrap it in `UCase()`

Comment: Congrats on the 100K :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `MID` and `LEFT`, assuming you have strings like:

```
Text1 - 123
Text2 - 456
Text3 - 789
```

You can get the first word of such a string in upper case through:

```
SUBname = Ucase(Split(String, " - ")(0))
```

The second part (no need for ucase on numbers):

```
SUBnum = Split(String, " - ")(1)
```